# Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your information

Tags: wordpress, namecheap

Good day all.
I have a WordPress website that I have transferred from siteground hosting to namecheap shared hosting, the domain is a local domain as .com.ng and SSL is configured but for some days now I always have difficulties accessing the backend and frontend on specific time (hours) 10:00 am- 2:00pm West Africa time. below is the message I always receive.

Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from com.ng (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).

Comment: Is your local time correctly configured on your computer?

Comment: What is the domain name reporting the error? There are many reasons for this error, the simplest is for one of us to look at the certificate returned from your endpoint. If you do not want to provide that information, you will need to update your question with a lot more details.

Comment: Yes, local time correctly configured.

Comment: The  domain name is schoolsupplyfactory.com.ng

Comment: @IshauMd - Your site does not have a problem. You probably did not wait long enough for the changes to update, or your browser is caching stale information. Reboot the system and try again, flush browser cache, flush DNS cache, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you. I have done all that severally, it usually occur at random time, sometimes it will work fine on mobile but not on desktop and if I try to access it from different device it wont work. then with time it will restore .

Comment: This sounds like either a proxy issue or an ISP issue.

Comment: @JohnHanley have tried all I could